# Xamarin Android App using FCM crashes at runtime due to java.lang.RuntimeException caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Android app developed in Xamarin crashes when notifications feature is implemented using FCM with linking set to "SDK Assemblies Only" in Relese

Below are the details,

`Xamarin   16.11.000.197 (d16-11@6934992)`
`Xamarin Designer   16.11.0.47 (remotes/origin/d16-11@e0d612363)`
`Xamarin Templates   16.10.5 (355b57a)`
`Xamarin.Android SDK   12.0.0.3 (d16-11/f0e3c2d)`
`Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   15.2.0.17 (738fde344)`

`Dex compiler = d8 Code Shrinker = r8 Linking = SdkOnly`

`"Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics" Version 119.0.1.1`
`"Xamarin.Firebase.Iid" Version 121.1.0.1`
`"Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version 122.0.0.1`
`"Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" Version 117.6.0.1`

I have tried updating nuget packages but it gives linking errors.
I also tried commenting out com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver and com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver from AndroidManifest.xml as FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken() is used.
App still crashes for FCM notification feature when linking set to "SDK Assemblies Only"

Crash details from Google Play Console :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4445)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:253)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2198)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8183)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:584)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1034)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:110)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4438)
```

Comment: Could you please post the full error log about this problem?   And you can try to set linking  to "none" to see the problem still exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help. By setting linking to 'none' all works fine in Release and in Debug. Crash issue is fixed now after adding -keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; } line in Proguard.cfg file